# android OpenCV-2.3.0 eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv

I followed [this](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Android2.3.0) guide on windows and i successfully installed the 
OpenCV_SAMPLE to my device with the "ant install" command. 
Ive also installed the CVCamera to my device in the same way without any errors..
Now i want to import this project in eclipse for further editing.
Ive first imported the android-opencv project in eclipse without facing any errors. 
Now when im trying to import the OpenCV_SAMPLE or the CVCamera to eclipse im getting the following errors..
It shows me the project with a "!" and i cant run it.

The problem is in these libraries..

`import com.opencv.camera.CameraConfig;

    import com.opencv.camera.NativePreviewer;

    import com.opencv.camera.NativeProcessor;

    import com.opencv.camera.NativeProcessor.PoolCallback;

    import com.opencv.jni.image_pool;

    import com.opencv.opengl.GL2CameraViewer;`

With these two im not getting any errors

`import com.theveganrobot.cvcamera.jni.Processor;

     import com.theveganrobot.cvcamera.jni.cvcamera;`

In the eclipse window ,problems->errors im getting these for my project
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The container 'Library Projects' references non existing library `'C:\OpenCVneon\OpenCV\android\android-opencv\bin\opencv.jar'`

The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved

Also in the project properties i have checked android-opencv "is library"

Answer (score 0):

`opencv.jar` should exist on your system. Try looking for it and changing the reference to it (deleting the one already there and then adding another one) or you may need to build it.

If you used the binaries, you will have to locate where this on your system, probably where you extracted the binaries.

Comment: Thanx for the answer, i made a search but i havent find anywhere the opencv.jar file..

Comment: You may have to build it then :)